# How can I get bootstrap responsive css work with yeoman bower

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yeoman, bower

I am using bower to get bootstrap lib, 
there is a bootstrap-responsive-2.3.2 in the \bower_components\bootstrap-sass 
Although I can manually import it by myself, I just wanna find out is there any way to import it with bower command?

Comment: Bower is a package manager. It doesn't deal with how/when these packages should be included within your code.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know bower fetches the specified dependencies. You probably want to look into grunt tasks something like [grunt-include-bootstrap](https://github.com/davewasmer/grunt-include-bootstrap) that will define a task using grunt and will add to your project page. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

In the main.scss file that ships with Yeoman (after running 'yo webapp' and using the default options), the '.container' max-width overrides the responsive defaults. Simply take it out (lines 74-76), and the >1200px states will show.

Answer (score 0):

This is simply done by adding

```
@import "bootstrap-sass/lib/responsive";
```

after

```
@import "bootstrap-sass/lib/bootstrap";
```

in your main.scss. It is as easy as that :-)